# Does a tensor quantity only depend on the vector field at a point?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In Riemannian geometry there are many functions that have vector fields as arguments. Some (like the curvature tensor) are tensorial and some (like $<\nabla_{X}Y,Z>$) are not. Does the value of a tensor at a point taking arguments which are vector fields depend ONLY on the vector fields at that point? (As opposed to the value of the vector fields in some open subset at the point, which is the case for the non tensor quantity I just gave.)

As an extension of this question, this occurred to me as I was reading a sentence in lemma in do carmo which states "Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold with curvature $R(X,Y)Z$. Given a parameterised surface $f(u,v)\subset M$ and $V$ a vector field on $f(u,v)$ define $R(\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} ) V $ in the obvious way. " But this is not really obvious to me. What if you can't extend the vector field locally to a vector field on $M$? Does this definition still make sense?

Comment: I'd start by saying $X \mapsto \nabla_X Y(p)$ and $Y \mapsto \nabla_X Y(p)$ are very different : in the former, $X$ can be a single vector of $T_pM$ the tangent space at $p$ (when $X$ is a vector field, we look implicitely at $X(p)$ so that $\nabla_X Y(p) \overset{def}= \nabla_{X(p)} Y(p)$), but in the latter, $Y$ has to be a vector (or tensor) field defined in the neighborhood of $p$, and differentiable at $p$

Comment: Yes of course. In this case the mapping is $C^{\infty}(M) $ linear in X but not in Y so I was wonder if this "locality" property is a general feature of maps that are linear in this way

Comment: Also this doesn't help with the second question because looking at the definition of curvature the V in my question should be defined on an open set

Comment: in the definition of tensor fields https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_field#The_C.E2.88.9E.28M.29_module_explanation there is the property $S(fX) = f S(X)$ for any smooth function $f : M \to \mathbb{R}$. $f$ can change the derivatives of $fX$ as we want without changing $(fX)(p)$, it should mean that $S(X)(p)$ doesn't depend on the derivatives of $X$, so that (whenever $X$ is continuous) $S(X)(p) = S_p X(p)$ for some tensor $S_p$. Now I admit proving it for the Riemann curvature tensor doesn't seem trivial, from the definition in term of the covariant derivatives and the Lie bracket.

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot!! Actually I think the same idea will show easily  that the vector field R(X,Y)Z depends only on $Z_p$ as we know that this is $C^{\infty} (M) $ in Z